# How to sort by senders' email address and not by display name in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sorting

Is there a way in Outlook 2013 to view multiple incoming email addresses as the same contact? For example:

Email #1 - Johnny Appleseed japple@yahoo.com

Email #2 - JAppleseed japple@yahoo.com

In the inbox I'd like to see both of them as Johnny Appleseed. Unfortunately, if they have their Yahoo account set up with one name, and their smartphone mail client set up with another name, they both come in differently. (even from the exact same email address) This makes sorting by sender difficult. At work we have many instances when a email conversation is started on one mail client, then continued on another client.

I'm not interested in conversation view, (I love it, but this is for my boss), because it's important to sort by sender and look through hundreds of emails.

Comment: i thought that if you had the Emailadress in your Local Outlook-Contacts then the Mails from this Adress will show up with the Name you gave them (no matter what the Sender it selfs had set as Name) - i'm not shure if this is limited to an specific Version of Outlook or Maybe it's a spezial Setting you have to make but the last time i used Outlook it was like this (but this was 3 years Ago since then we are using Macs @Work)

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I ran a test and the name always shows up as the sender has it set up on their mail client. If their iPhone is set up as John Appleseed, and their desktop Yahoo account is set up as J Appleseed, they will come through differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the email address as a column in outlook as described here: [Show sender’s e-mail address as a column in message view](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm)

**Quote:**

Download the [configuration files](http://www.howto-outlook.com/files/viewsenderaddress.zip)

Copy it to this folder (assuming WINx64 on english system)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\FORMS\1033

**Installing config file file (.cfg)**

- File-> Options-> section Advanced-> options group Developers-> button Custom Forms…-> button Manage Forms…
- In the Forms Manager dialog, press the Install… button.
- Browse to the location where you’ve placed viewsenderaddress.cfg
- Select the file and press Open
- A property window will open with the details of the cfg-file. Press OK to confirm and close the dialog
- Press Close to close the Forms Manager dialog
- Press OK until all open dialogs are close and you are being returned to the main Outlook window

**Configuring the view to add the column**

- Open the View Settings dialog (tab View-> button View Settings)
- Press the button called Fields
- From the dropdown list called “Select available columns from” select; Forms…
- Here select “Sender’s Email Address” and press “Add ->
- From the dropdown list called “Select available columns from” select; Sender’s Email Address
- Select “From E-mail Address” and press “Add ->
- Use the Move Up and Move Down buttons to place it in the location you want

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it works for me. So, there is no way that you know of to have Outlook see two incoming emails and display them with the same name? It seems like an easy function for Microsoft to include.

Comment: @TonyTambe - no, this is the only way I know, displaying the email address.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the answer since it seems there is no better way. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Visual Basic editor by pressing Alt + F11. Click Insert - Module. Paste the code below.

Go into Outlook - View Tab - Add Columns - New Column - Name = Domain, Type = Text, Format = Text - Add this from the User-defined fields to show in outlook.

Select all messages in inbox (ctrl + A) - press Alt + F11 to open the module just created. Press F5 to run. If you have a lot of emails you may have to select batches of 200 emails or so and then press Alt+ F11, then F5.

VBA Code:

```
Sub ListSelectionDomain()

Dim aObj As Object

Dim oProp As Outlook.UserProperty

Dim sDomain

On Error Resume Next

For Each aObj In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Set oMail = aObj

sDomain = Right(oMail.SenderEmailAddress, Len(oMail.SenderEmailAddress) - InStr(0, oMail.SenderEmailAddress))

Set oProp = oMail.UserProperties.Add("Domain", olText, True)

oProp.Value = sDomain

oMail.Save

Err.Clear

Next

End Sub
```